# Есть ли готовый метод в Apps Script, который выдаёт массив с индексами искОмого элемента?

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Допустим, есть массив var arrayQuestion = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0];

Необходимо получить позиции, где встречается единица.
Метод indexOf() выдаёт по одному результату на запрос.

arrayQuestion.indexOF(1); // результат 1
arrayQuestion.indexOF(1, 2); // результат 3

А нет ли готового изящного метода (решения), где на выходе будет массив из индексов единицы в массиве arrayQuestion?

То есть в нашем случае это должен быть arrayResult = [1, 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, понравится такой вариант:

```
var arrayQuestion = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0];
var indexes = arrayQuestion.reduce(function(acc, cur, index) {
  if (cur == 1) acc.push(index);
  return acc;
}, []);
Logger.log(indexes);  // [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

вот вполне изящный вариант:

```js
const reduceFn = (prev, item, index) => item === 1 ? [...prev, index] : prev;

[0, 1, 0, 1, 0].reduce(reduceFn, []); //[1, 3];
```

Comment: Вариант и вправду выглядит очень локонично, но, к сожалению, редактору Google Apps Script этот синтаксис не понравился. А Вы не могли бы адаптировать этот код для Гугла?

Answer (score 0):

Пока что лучшее из всего, что удалось найти (на что не ругается Гугл) - вариант ответа в англоязычной версии этого сайта: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array):

```
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == val) {
            indexes.push(i);
        }
    }
    return indexes;
}


 Logger.log(getAllIndexes([0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function indexes(arr, value) {
  let result = [];
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(arr)) {
    if (value === 1) result.push(+key);
  }
  return result;
}

let arr = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0];

console.log(indexes(arr, 1)); // [1, 3]
```

Comment: К сожалению, та же проблема, что и в ответе @17axaH - синтаксис не совместим с Google Apps Script.